# Building a family tree from mysql database, which has some schema

Tags: php, mysql

I just need a php code which retrieves data from mysql and build a family tree.

Sql data has the following schema.

```
(Id, Name, ParentId1, ParentId2)
```

I'll insert the data as

```
INSERT INTO table_name (`Id`, `Name`, `ParentId1`, `ParentId2`)
VALUES ('100', 'Name_1', 'Parent_1', 'Parent_2')
```

If 0 is specified for parentId1 and ParentId2 then he is in top of the family.
**The code should generate the family tree based on the parentId1 and parentId2.** Based on the matching parentId, name should attach to the parent. Optionally If I specify a relation between two example marriage, they should be connected in the code.
**Its ok if you just tell me an overview of how to design or approach.**

Comment: Note that, by convention, NULL is commonly used to represent orphans.

Comment: if you decided to use ready made jquery tree plugins.most of them requires json data as input.create required json data on serverside using querys and loops.

Comment: Ok, let it be like that. Can you tell me how to approach

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937909/genealogy-tree-mysql

Comment: This is not a simple problem... you might need to use recursive queries.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to do this.
This function I have created return a table whit a linear data tree

You can follow the idea and customize to you

```
static function display_child_nodes($parent_id, $level,$data,$index,$dr){//first level=  NULL,0
       global $data, $index,$dr;

       if(is_null($parent_id)){
            $parent_id ="NULL";
       }

       if (isset($index[$parent_id])) {           
            foreach ($index[$parent_id] as $id) {
                $mark=NULL;
                if($level<1){
                    $content = $data[$id][PROCEDIEMNTOS_PROFISSIONAIS_NOME];

                }
                else{
                    $content =str_repeat("&nbsp", $level*2) .$data[$id][PROCEDIEMNTOS_PROFISSIONAIS_NOME];
                }
                $dr[$id]=$content;
                self::display_child_nodes($id, $level + 1,$data,$index,$dr);
            }        
    }    
    return $dr;   
}
```